# how to localize string text in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, translate

Section(footer: Text(fuels.count > 0 ? "Last Odometer Entry: (String(format: "%ld", locale: Locale.current, fuels.last!.odometer)) km" : ""))

Hi all,
I need to translate this text: "**Last Odometer Entry:**" but this is not enclosed in quotes, so I couldn't translate as I do with other text strings, for example:
Text("Cost:")
becomes
"Cost:" = "Cost"
or:
Text(settingsViewModel.fuelType == .electric ? "Charge:" : "Fuel Amount:")
becomes
"Charge:" = "Charge:"
"Fuel Amount:" = "Fuel Amount:"
This works.

But how do I translate the text described above?

Thanks for your support